# "мягонькой" — есть ли такое слово в русском языке?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Пытаюсь понять, есть ли в русском языке слово "мягонькой". Язык в данном случае понимается широко, включая разговорную и диалектную лексику.

Пока удалось найти слова *мягонький* и разговорное слово *мяконький*, встречающееся в т.ч. в русской классике.

Comment: См. https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22мягонькой%22+словарь&newwindow=1&client=safari&hl=ru-ru&prmd=inv&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiljZ_m_ujrAhVw-SoKHcqIC2QQ_AUoBnoECAoQBg&biw=768&bih=960&dpr=2

Answer (score 1):

1. В орфографическом словаре на Грамоте.ру  указаны следующие варианты: ***мягенький и мягонькой, мякенький и мяконькой.*** У Ефремовой они даются  с указанием (разг.). Из этого следует, что разговорные  варианты тоже **нормируются**, но что варианта  «мягонькой» с окончанием ОЙ в словарях нет.
2. Окончание ОЙ является **устаревшим**, но оно может применяться в поэтической и народной речи, в то же время нормированным такое окончание не считается.

Подробно об окончании ОЙ можно, например,  посмотреть [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462057/Почему-прилагательные-в-начальной-форме-имеют-два-вида-окончаний-ой-и-ый-ий](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462057/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B9)

3. **Про диалекты** такая информация.

Имя прилагательное в диалектологии https://studfile.net/preview/7357489/page:4/

Система склонения прилагательных совпадает с литературным языком. Но наиболее яркой отличительной чертой является наличие стяженных форм (зерно крупно, носки суконны, зима холодна), а также **взаимодействие твердого и мягкого вариантов:** летной урожай, твоей рубахой - нижная полка, тим домом.

Таким образом, можно сделать вывод, что  **в диалектной речи такой вариант возможен,** но этот вопрос требует специального изучения.

Answer (score 0):

Да. В подобных прилагательных после г/к/х возможно написание и -оньк- и -еньк- (кроме слова махонький)