# Почему прилагательные в начальной форме имеют два вида окончаний: ой и ый/ий?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, окончания

Как известно, безударное окончание прилагательных  ый/ий **нельзя проверить** вопросительным словом «какой»,  эти окончания запоминаются **как исключение.** Написание считается традиционно-историческим, **но в чем заключается эта традиция и эта история?**

Также тема связана с недавним вопросом на форуме о слове «мягонькой» [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462001/мягонькой-есть-ли-такое-слово-в-русском-языке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462001/%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5)

Я  сама  дам первый  ответ на заданный вопрос в соответствии с материалом статьи http://bibl.tikva.ru/base/B952/B952Part19-116.php

Ответ по сути является пересказом содержания  **в доступной и понятной  форме** как для школьников, так и для всех пользователей языка. Поэтому мне будут интересны любые замечания и дополнения.

Answer (score 2):

Этот вопрос может задать любой любознательный  ученик, начиная с первого класса. Что же ему ответить? Я предлагаю рассказать ему такую историю.

**Великое противостояние окончаний**

КакОЙ краской ты  нарисуешь цветок? ГолубОЙ, краснОЙ, синЕЙ? Словом «какой» мы проверяем безударное окончание Т.п. – ой/ ей.

КакОЙ ты выберешь цвет? ГолубОЙ, краснЫЙ, синИЙ?  Безударное окончание  в И.п. нельзя проверить, его надо запомнить. Но почему?

1. Письменная русская  речь создана **на старославянской основе**, и там использовались окончания ЫЙ/ИЙ. А окончание ОЙ/ЕЙ – это **собственно русский вариант**, он соответствовал реальному произношению. И поэтому грамотные люди писали ЫЙ/ИЙ, но произносить могли **оба варианта**, то есть окончание ОЙ тоже.  Вероятно, и на письме окончание ОЙ также стало употребляться.
2. **Ломоносов хотел узаконить** существующий произносительный вариант ОЙ в качестве нормы, чтобы он соответствовал ударному окончанию. В "Российской грамматике" он употребляет такие, к примеру, прилагательные с окончанием ОЙ: сильной, скверной, сладкой, истинной и истинный, но богатый.  Однако вариант ЫЙ/ИЙ **активно сопротивлялся**. У него было **преимущество** в том, что он графически отличался от окончаний других падежей и был более узнаваем на письме.
3. Далее началось **стилистическое противостояние**: высокая, книжная. правильная речь – это ЫЙ/ИЙ, а ОЙ – разговорное, обычное окончание.  В частности, в причастиях употреблялся только славянский вариант *написанный*, а в прилагательных  допускались оба: *писаный и писаной*. И даже  одно и то же слово могло иметь разную **стилевую характеристику**: добрый (книжн.) – доброй (разг.), сладкий (книжн.)  – сладкой (разг.).
4. Но далее (с конца XVIII века) книжный вариант  ЫЙ/ИЙ **окончательно закрепился** в языке, вытеснив вариант ОЙ и по письму, и по произношению, то есть именно он стал **нормативным.**
5. Особо следует выделить прилагательные **с заднеязычными согласными Г, К, Х:** строгий, широкий, тихий и т.п. Старое русское окончание ЕЙ не сохранилось, поэтому вариантов  здесь не было.  Но когда-то окончание таких прилагательных произносилось так, как если бы вместо ИЙ было написано ОЙ: широ/къй/, стро/гъй/, ти/хъй/. В современной речи такое произношение представлено, но считается нормативным лишь для сцены. Обычным, бытовым является произношение: широ/к'ий/, стро/г'ий/, ти/х'ий/ (с редуцированным /и/).
6. Итак, **устаревшее произношение и написание  ОЙ  перестало быть нормой** уже в начале XIX века, но сохранилось **в народной и поэтической речи**. Поэтому в произведениях художественной литературы у имён прилагательных можно встретить безударное   ОЙ, которое отражает на письме  соответствующее произношение. Такие формы считаются устаревшими.  Например: Белеет парус **одинокой** (М. Лермонтов). Дуб стоит **высокой** (народная поэзия).

Вероятно, **в диалектах**  также можно встретить  собственно русское ОЙ: Какой у него песок-от?  **Мягонькой?** ― улыбнувшись, спросил Дюков. [П. И. Мельников-Печерский. В лесах. Книга первая (1871-1874)]